# Как с помощью numpy посчитать сколько раз один элемент встречается с другим?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

В общем условие и данные:

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 4, 5],
    [2, 3, 4, 5]
])
```

Необходимо с помощью numpy посчитать, сколько раз каждый элемент встречается с другим. Т.е. сколько раз 1 встречается с 2, с 3, с 4, с 5;
2 c 1, 2 c 3 и т.д. В одной строке не может быть одинаковых цифр (Но это и так видно).
Есть у кого нибудь мысли, как это сделать с помощью numpy. Только начинаю изучать, кажется вроде всё просто, а идей почему то нет! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я бы сделал как-нибудь так:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import collections

arr = np.array([
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 5]
    ])

res = collections.defaultdict(int)
pairs = list(itertools.combinations(np.unique(arr),2))

for row in arr:
    for i in pairs:
        res[i] += int(all(np.isin(i,row)))

print(res)
```

получим словарь где keys - пары значений, а values - количество их "встреч":

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 2, (1, 4): 3, (1, 5): 2, (2, 3): 2, (2, 4): 3, (2, 5): 2, (3, 4): 3, (3, 5): 2, (4, 5): 3})
```

***UPDATE***

Для того, чтобы вывести результаты для какого-то конкретного числа, можно сделать так:

```
num = 2 # число, которое нас интересует
for key in res.keys():
    if num in key:
        skey = sorted(key, reverse=True) if key[0] != num else key
        print(f"{skey[0]} и {skey[1]} встречаются в матрице {res[key]} раз(a)")
```

Получим:

```
2 и 1 встречаются в матрице 2 раз(a)
2 и 3 встречаются в матрице 2 раз(a)
2 и 4 встречаются в матрице 3 раз(a)
2 и 5 встречаются в матрице 2 раз(a)
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что чисто средствами numpy этого сделать нельзя?

Comment: И ещё вопрос, в вашем варианте есть вывод количества 1 и 2, но 2 и 1 нет. Как сделать чтобы было?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, чисто векторизированными функциями numpy? Я не большой знаток, но мне кажется, что нельзя. Что касается второго вопроса - какая, по-вашему, разница должна быть между парами (1 и 2) и (2 и 1)?

Comment: Да, имею ввиду именно векторизированными функциями numpy. Я же говорил, что только начинаю изучать, вот мне непонятно как потом выбрать из полученного результата, данные по цифре 2 например?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.